# Data driven colour in D3.JS SVG circles

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

!Simplified the question!

The attached code generates a pattern of 64 small circles leading to larger circles.

The question is regarding driving the colour of each circle based on a dataset, such as below, where each circle can be assigned a colour based on a data value from 1-6:
Example dataset for one section:
[1,3,5,2,**3**...] Here, the first 4 numbers represent the value of the first set of 4 small circles leading out to one of the large circles, and the last number represents the value of that large circle.

If someone can help drive the colour of each circle based on a 'hard coded' dataset per the example above, I will then look to attach the dataset to my database as a next step. (The final result will load this image based on a database string of values that will drive the colours)

Note: Ideally the circles in the code all need shifting around a little so that they fit inside the 4 quadrants as well, but they key challenge here is assigning based on a dataset.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>D3 Test</title>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">

</style>

</head> 
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">


    var width = height = 500;
    var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10)
      .domain(d3.range(16));

    var data1 = d3.range(16);
    var dataRadius = [70, 110, 150, 190, 230];

    svg.append("circle").attr("cx", width / 2)
        .attr("cy", height / 2)
        .attr("r", 30)
        .attr("fill", "yellow");

    //my additions

    svg.append("circle").attr("cx", 40)
        .attr("cy", 40)
        .attr("r", 30)
        .attr("fill", "lightgrey")
        .attr("stroke-width", "1")
        .attr("stroke", "grey");

    svg.append("circle").attr("cx", width - 40)
        .attr("cy", height - 40)
        .attr("r", 30)
        .attr("fill", "lightgrey")
        .attr("stroke-width", "1")
        .attr("stroke", "grey");

    svg.append("circle").attr("cx", width - 40)
        .attr("cy", 40)
         .attr("r", 30)
        .attr("fill", "lightgrey")
        .attr("stroke-width", "1")
        .attr("stroke", "grey");

    svg.append("circle").attr("cx", 40)
        .attr("cy", height - 40)
        .attr("r", 30)
        .attr("fill", "lightgrey")
        .attr("stroke-width", "1")
        .attr("stroke", "grey");

    svg.append("line") 
        .attr("y1", height /2) 
        .attr("y2" , height /2) 
        .attr("x1" , 0) 
        .attr("x2" , width)
        .attr("stroke-width","2") 
        .attr("stroke", "black");

    svg.append("line")
     .attr("x1", height / 2)
     .attr("x2", height / 2)
     .attr("y1", 0)
     .attr("y2", width)
     .attr("stroke-width", "2")
     .attr("stroke", "black");

    //end of my additions
    var groups = svg.selectAll(".groups")
        .data(dataRadius)
        .enter()
        .append("g");

    var circles = groups.selectAll(".circles")
        .data(data1)
        .enter()
        .append("circle");

    circles.attr("cx", function (d, i) { var radius = this.parentNode.__data__; return width / 2 + (radius * Math.sin(i * (360 / (data1.length) * Math.PI / 180))) })
        .attr("cy", function (d, i) { var radius = this.parentNode.__data__; return height / 2 + (radius * Math.cos(i * (360 / (data1.length) * Math.PI / 180))) })
        .attr("r", function () { return this.parentNode.__data__ == 230 ? 24 : 14 })
        .attr("fill", function (d, i) { return i == 13 || i == 14 ? color(i - 2) : "#ccc" });
</script>   

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll provide an *ad hoc* solution: since I am the one that wrote this code you posted in your question, I know how the circles are drawn: counterclockwise, from the centre to the outside. That being said, my solution involves classes.

If we add this simple line at the end of the `circles` variable:

```
.attr("class", function(d){ return "circle" + d});
```

We will set a class to the circles. But the interesting is that we have 16 circles per turn, so, all the circles in the next (external) ring will have the same class! And, as they are drawn from inside to outside, a simple:

```
d3.selectAll(".circle8")
```

Will select all the 5 circles belong to the class `.circle8` in the order you want.

So, if you set an array like this:

```
var colour8 = ["yellow", "yellow", "tan", "red", "purple"];
```

They will be painted in that order, from inside to outside.

This is a demo showing it. The classes start with 0 at 6 o'clock and goes counterclockwise, finishing with 15 around 7 o'clock. These are the colours:

```
var color0 = ["teal", "blue", "red", "red", "cyan"];//6 o'clock
var color8 = ["red", "red", "red", "red", "pink"];//12 o'clock
var color9 = ["tan", "tan", "green", "cyan", "lime"];//just next to it
```

Check the demo:

```js
var width = height = 500;
    var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10)
      .domain(d3.range(16));

    var data1 = d3.range(16);
    var dataRadius = [70, 110, 150, 190, 230];

    svg.append("circle").attr("cx", width / 2)
        .attr("cy", height / 2)
        .attr("r", 30)
        .attr("fill", "yellow");

    //my additions

    svg.append("circle").attr("cx", 40)
        .attr("cy", 40)
        .attr("r", 30)
        .attr("fill", "lightgrey")
        .attr("stroke-width", "1")
        .attr("stroke", "grey");

    svg.append("circle").attr("cx", width - 40)
        .attr("cy", height - 40)
        .attr("r", 30)
        .attr("fill", "lightgrey")
        .attr("stroke-width", "1")
        .attr("stroke", "grey");

    svg.append("circle").attr("cx", width - 40)
        .attr("cy", 40)
         .attr("r", 30)
        .attr("fill", "lightgrey")
        .attr("stroke-width", "1")
        .attr("stroke", "grey");

    svg.append("circle").attr("cx", 40)
        .attr("cy", height - 40)
        .attr("r", 30)
        .attr("fill", "lightgrey")
        .attr("stroke-width", "1")
        .attr("stroke", "grey");

    svg.append("line") 
        .attr("y1", height /2) 
        .attr("y2" , height /2) 
        .attr("x1" , 0) 
        .attr("x2" , width)
        .attr("stroke-width","2") 
        .attr("stroke", "black");

    svg.append("line")
     .attr("x1", height / 2)
     .attr("x2", height / 2)
     .attr("y1", 0)
     .attr("y2", width)
     .attr("stroke-width", "2")
     .attr("stroke", "black");

    //end of my additions
    var groups = svg.selectAll(".groups")
        .data(dataRadius)
        .enter()
        .append("g");

    var circles = groups.selectAll(".circles")
        .data(data1)
        .enter()
        .append("circle");

    circles.attr("cx", function (d, i) { var radius = this.parentNode.__data__; return width / 2 + (radius * Math.sin(i * (360 / (data1.length) * Math.PI / 180))) })
        .attr("cy", function (d, i) { var radius = this.parentNode.__data__; return height / 2 + (radius * Math.cos(i * (360 / (data1.length) * Math.PI / 180))) })
        .attr("r", function () { return this.parentNode.__data__ == 230 ? 24 : 14 })
    .attr("fill", "#ccc")
    .attr("class", function(d){ return "circle" + d});
    
  var color0 = ["teal", "blue", "red", "red", "cyan"];
    var color8 = ["red", "red", "red", "red", "pink"];
    var color9 = ["tan", "tan", "green", "cyan", "lime"];
    
  svg.selectAll(".circle0").attr("fill", function(d,i){
    return color0[i];
    });
    
  svg.selectAll(".circle8").attr("fill", function(d,i){
    return color8[i];
    });
    
  svg.selectAll(".circle9").attr("fill", function(d,i){
    return color9[i];
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

This is just the general idea. Of course, you'll have to write functions to avoid redundant code.